# Why Are Openings Named After Countries?

Tags: opening

This has been bothering me from when I was little. Why are openings most commonly named after a country? For example: Sicilian, Scotch, Spanish, etc...

Comment: @IanBush I think your comment is a very good answer. The only thing I might add to it, and feel free to use this, is that sometimes they are also named after a place where a tournament took place (the Catalan I think). You should really move your comments to an answer as they are a good one, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, especially looking at that link you just provided, there are so many that it shows that the questions is so broad that your answer is a very good general answer. No one would expect every opening's origin to be explained, and that is a good overall answer that could be applied to many of the other openings.

Comment: Is Sicily considered a country?

Comment: Quite possibly Sicily was a country when the opening was "invented"!

Comment: Oh oops, I didn't check if it's actually a country.

Comment: Sicily was one of the states that later became unified as Italy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a variety of reasons why openings are commonly named after nations (but *most* commonly would surprise me), maybe due to an individual player of the nation, e.g. Spanish (Ruy Lopez), English (Staunton), maybe due to a group of players in one nation e.g. Italian, maybe due to an event involving the nation e.g. Scotch (named for a correspondence match between Edinburgh and London in the 1800s), and I suspect a number of other reasons, including "we don't really know"

[Wikipedia list of chess openings named after places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_openings_named_after_places) might be a good place to start researching this

Comment: Another good reference is the book _Chess Opening Names: The Fascinating & Entertaining History Behind the First Few Moves_.

Comment: Examples from the book mentioned by @ithb  English  - because Staunton pioneered it.  Scotch - From a Scottish - English club match started in 1824 where the Scotts used this opening.  French - Match between London and Paris 1834.  Paris won with the novelty 1. ..e6.  The book is humorous and contains no games.